# How can I implement Basic Authentication against a database?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have a database with usernames and passwords and I want to use it for authenticating ASP.net web page users.

I know how to do it with a webpage form (i.e. with just the simple form in HTML, C# provider and my web.config with `authentication mode="Forms"`).

However I'd like to have a *Popup Modal Dialog*, see below (such as if I use `authentication mode="Windows"` or on Apache server `.htaccess` + `.htpasswd`).

[image: Basic Authentication]

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [this tutorial](http://blog.smithfamily.dk/post/implementing-basic-authentication-in-aspnet-20) which describes how to implement your own Basic Authentication `HttpModule`.

The example doesn't include the database integration, but it does indicate where you should do it, and takes care of most of the hard work.

Because it is an `HttpModule` you'll be able to reuse it easily in other project simply by referencing the library and linking it in your `web.config`.

Comment: @stephen I have updated the link. The blog owner altered the link title to include hyphens between words. Sorted now :)

Comment: Probably this is the link : http://blog.smithfamily.dk/post/implementing-basic-authentication-in-aspnet-20/